# Where's this "vibrant fall foliage" "along the shores of Jasper's Athabasca River"?

Tags: identify-this, jasper

Marc Adamus, the photographer, didn't disclose his email or contact details [on his website](https://www.marcadamus.com/photo/endless-beauty/?search=alberta). I submitted the form twice, but got no reply after a month.

Where is this on Jasper's Athabasca River?

> #### Endless Beauty (2007)
>
> **Jasper National Park, Alberta**
>
> Vibrant fall foliage including Wild Rose, Aspen, Willow and Cottonwood along the shores of Jasper's Athabasca River with sunset over the Canadian Rockies beyond.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the same location from Google Maps: https://goo.gl/maps/bCCu817YFpo3F9AL9. It's a couple of km south of Athabasca Falls on Highway 93. Obviously the Street View photo below was not taken at the same time of year!

[image]

Comment: Good find!  I recognised the river from when I was there, but you've nailed the location!

Comment: wow!! how did you find out?

Comment: @MarkdaSilva: Mostly, the mountains are very distinctive. Knowing it was around Jasper, I just followed the river using Google Earth until I found the right mountains. Then it was just a matter of lining them up correctly against the river in the foreground.